# Authentication between Web App, Web API & Mobile App

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I need suggestions for authentication between these three applications (web,api,mobile).

**Use Case**

- I have .Net Core Web API which works with basic authentication (i.e.
  username & password in header).
- I need to consume that API in my .Net Core Web App and Xamarin mobile app.
- I want to integrate security model between all three applications.

**Problem Statements**

- I don't have knowledge about how the same authentication can work for Web App & API.
- I don't want to use any third-party authentication provider. I would
  like to have my users in database only.
- What is best way to secure my API?
- Once I secure my Web API, How about authentication on Web App &
  Mobile App?

I know *this is a broad question* but simplest answer/way will help me to decide further path. I have enough knowledge about authentication like AD, OAuth, Open Connect, JWT But honestly not sure how to use it in my scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be have your API work with JWT and connect to a database holding your users info. You'd have a route that receives username and password and returns a token. For all the authenticated routes, the request needs this token on the header. For the clients (Web App and Xamarin), you'd store the received token as a cookie and send it together on every API call.

Comment: Thanks. but end user can easily grab token from cookie and can send separate request to API.

Comment: Sure. If the user has a token, it means the user was successfully authenticated, which means it's fine for your user to see data from the API. If you want your user to not see everything, now it's a permission problem, not authentication. If you're worried about someone sniffing the cookie, use SSL.

Comment: Agree, thanks! Initially I will implement this logic. For better security, can you suggest more secure way?

Comment: To enhance security, you may have an expiration date on the cookie. After some time (say 1 hour), the user has to provide credentials again. It mitigates damage if the token was compromised (which is unlikely using SSL).

Comment: How about for web app, do the cookie way, and for mobile app, use the token? Any major difference?